# How to use DateTime to make a countdown calendar in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm currently learning C# and making some console applications.
I want to create a console app which take two dates as parameters **(YEAR/MONTH/DAY)**.

One for the start, and another one for the end.
I've tried to make a difference between the two of them, but I get the following error message:

*"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'System.DateTime' [Calendar]"*

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2017, 11, 17);
        int result = DateTime.Compare(t, end);
        TimeSpan timeSpan = end - t;
        DateTime days_left = timeSpan;

        Console.WriteLine("Left", timeSpan.TotalDays);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

In this version, I enter the end date in the code.

Thanks in advance for your help and for your time,

Comment: You cannot cast a TimeSpan as a DateTime.  Simply remove the line DateTime days_left = timespan; and your code will compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is the problem:

```
DateTime days_left = timeSpan;
```

When you declared `timeSpan` you gave it the type `TimeSpan`. On the very next line, you try to assign `timeSpan` to `days_left`, which is a variable of type `DateTime`. This is not possible, as you cannot directly cast one type to the other.

If you think about it, this line doesn't even make sense, as `DateTime` objects represent a date not a time span. That is what `TimeSpan` objects are for!
Simply remove that line and your program will compile no problem.

Also, if I may make a suggestion, do not directly subtract `DateTime`s like you have done here:

```
var timeSpan = end - t;
```

Instead use [`DateTime.Subtract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var timeSpan = end.Subtract(t);
```

This is the recommended approach when dealing with the difference between `DateTime`s, as it offers benefits such as adjusting for different time zones.

Finally, note my usage of the `var` keyword instead of explicitly declaring the type. This is a common coding convention in C# that I wish I knew as a beginner.

Here is a revised version of your code. Take some tips from it if you want for programs you write in the future:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now; // Descriptive variable names
    var endDate = new DateTime(2017, 11, 17);

    double remainingDays = endDate.Subtract(currentDate).TotalDays; //TimeSpan stores everything in doubles instead of integers

    Console.WriteLine("Days left: {0}", remainingDays); // Use String.Format formatting
    Console.ReadLine(); // Use readline so that program only exists when ENTER is pressed
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your help, It fixed all my issues

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this

```
DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
DateTime end = new DateTime(2017, 11, 17);
int result = DateTime.Compare(t, end);
TimeSpan timeSpan = end.Subtract(t);
```